# Question on proof of irrational of $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: proof-explanation, irrational-numbers

I am able to follow every step in the standard proof by contradiction that $x^2 = 2$ has no solutions in $\mathbb{Q}$ except for one line (paraphrasing):

> Assume there is such an $x$, and write $x = \frac{m}{n}$ where $m$ and $n$ have no common factors.

I know this is trying to say "$m$ and $n$ are relatively prime,'' $\gcd(m,n) = 1$, etc. But $1$ is a common factor even if that is the case. Is it convention to not consider $1$ a "common factor"?

I apologize if this is trivial. I am trying to understand the language used.

Comment: It should be 'where $m$ and $n$ have no common factors **other than 1**'. Which book is this?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is *convention* but as *EVERY* pair of integers *ALWAYS* have $1$ as a factor in common, when referring to the term "common factor" it is usually understood in context that we are considering factors other than $1$.  Otherwise it'd be very tedious to talk of common factors and *always* mutter under our breath "other than $1$" which we'd always have to do as the common factor $1$ will *never* be significant.  .... Still you are correct and the text should have been more careful.

Comment: ... so don't worry.  Some texts are more precise than others, some use natural language, others formal language, and some archaic  and forced.  You understood the intent.

Comment: I would say that there is nothing wrong with this formulation , the usual meaning of "factor" is a nontrivial one , usually the trivial factors $1$ and the number itself are omitted. Although some authors probably handle it in a different way.

Comment: A formulation avoiding this "issue" would have been "coprime" , which is the most common formulation of what is meant.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the author meant that $m$ and $n$ have no common **prime** factors.

Answer (score 1):

A very good spot. Mathematical proof is all about precision in the details, and this is a detail that has been missed by the author.

The way I've known the proof to be written is that $m$ and $n$ are chosen such that the fraction $\frac mn$ is in simplest form (I.e. can't be cancelled down), which essentially conveys that they must have no common factor except $1$.